# How to use Combobox's values in Query

Tags: c#, combobox, selecteditem, selectedvalue

Im using Combobox filled with Tables Names.
When I made Insert command and determine the table name by getting the values of the Combobox
it didn't work

```
           private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Conn.Open();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
            }
        Conn.Close();  

    }

//cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into dbo."+ comboBox1.SelectedItems.ToString()     +"(Phone, Email, Address) values('" + txt1.Text + "','" + txt2.Text + "','" + txt3.Text + "')", Conn);
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: Except that you have to use SelectedItem and not SelectedItems (that does not exist), your code to read the selected value in the combobox seems right. I suppose you have some problem with the connection (is it open when you execute the command?) or with escaping (if you have an ' in your txt controls your sqlString does not work. To find what is happening I suggest you to analyze the InnerException of your Exception, because SqlException is to generic. Hope to help.

Answer (score 1):

[Combobox article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/combobox-in-C-Sharp/)

You can find there a very good resource for everything for combobox. You can use the datasource property and let know the values and display for what you need.

```
comboBox1.datasource = datatable;
comboBox1.displayname = "ColumnNameForDisplayName";
comboBox1.valuename = "ColumnsNameForValueName";
```